# VirtualTreeView - Embarcadero C++ Builder XE7 - 64 bits

Tags: c++, 64-bit, c++builder, virtualtreeview, c++builder-xe7

I've just downloaded last version of [VirtualTreeView](https://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/).

I've been able to generate the runtime and design packages in 32bits with Embarcadero C++ Builder XE7. 
But when trying to build the runtime one in 64 bits I'm getting this error:

> [DCC Fatal Error] E2202 Required package 'DesignIDE' not found

I've already checked that the runtime package doesn't require `designide.bpi`. Any idea of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded the latest version from the VirtualTree from here: 
https://virtual-treeview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk.

Since the designtime package doesn't have a 64 bit configuration (Which makes sense because the IDE is a 32 bit app) you must have tried to compile the runtime package. But I can compile the runtime package without a problem.

That's why I would like to ask you if you tried to compile the same version as me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to compile the designtime package. Only the design time package has a dependency on the package "DesignIde". Since the Delphi IDE is 32Bit all design time package can be 32Bit only too and will fail with this error if compiled for 64Bit. Did you perhaps try build the entire project group for 64Bit?

Comment: We're only trying to compile the Runtime package in 64 bits and it doesn't require "Designide.bpi"
It requires: rtl.bpi, vcl.bpi, vclactnband.bpi, vclx.bpi and xmlrtl.bpi
And links statically to shell32.a